# Session mixup for jsf sessionscope and jaas login module

Tags: java, jsf, session, jboss, jaas

We have a `CustomLoginModule` (extending a `UsernamePasswordLoginModule`) that puts all user and session references in a map at login time. They are stored in an `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` bean.

At logout, these references are removed. To capture unexpected logouts, the method to remove these references is also called from the `@PreDestroy` method of a `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` bean.

When a user logs in at two locations, the first location's session is invalidated, and it's reference is removed from the map.
This means that when a user logs in at a second location, the corresponding record is removed from the map, and then the `@PreDestroy` method tries to remove it again.

Not a big problem you will say, we'll just pass the currect session reference from the `@PreDestroy` method, and compare that with the session in the map, and remove the session, only if both are equal.
However, and herein lies my question, apparently the `@PreDestroy` method of the NEW instance is called on session logout. After that `@Predestroy` method is called, the same session bean happily continues to function.

I'm not really interested in alternatives, since there are plenty. I am just wondering how this is possible.

The classes in question are too complicated to paste here, but I tried to render their intentions:

login module:

```
public class CustomLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule {
    login(){
        SessionMap.addToMap(username, currentSession);
    }
}
```

ApplicationScoped:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SessionMap{
    addToMap(String username, HttpSession currentSession){
         // get previously present session
         previousSession.invalidate(); // this triggers the predestroy of the sessionscoped
         // remove previous session from map
         // put new session in map
    }
}
```

SessionScoped:

```
@SessionScoped
public MySessionBean{
    @PreDestroy
    public void removeSession(){
        // this predestroy is called after the session is invalidated in the addtomap method
        // however, if you log the hash of this class, you will see that the second
        // class's predestroy is called, not the first
        SessionMap.removeFromMap(username, currentSession);
    }
}
```